# What's SAP Fiori ScfldMasterController?

Tags: sap-fiori

When I build SAP Fiori Master Detail application, I notice this `ScfldMasterController` from Opportunity sample application and wonder if I also should use this controller for my application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use that if you have a old code. Scaffolding classes were created by SAP to do the basic setup of the project like oDATA URL, project resources, component initialization etc.
It's deprecated now with SAP UI5 libs 1.4X. In Fact the whole project structure is changed a lot since then.
I would recommned that you use SAP WebIDE (available with HANA Cloud Platform https://account.hana.ondemand.com/) and use Master-Detail Project template to create your project.